# Can someone give me an example of how to work out an exact linear second order differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a theorem that states:

If an equation $P(x)y''+Q(x)y'+R(x)y=0$

can be written in the form:

$$[P(x)y']'+[f(x)y]'=0$$

then the equation is said to be exact.

Now I need to expand and equate the coefficients of these equations to show that a necessary condition for an equation to be exact is...

$$P''(x)-Q'(x)+R(x)=0$$

I began to expand the second equation but I do not know where to go from there.

Comment: Make an edit to your post to show us your working when expanding the brackets so we can see what you have done. After expanding and equating you should have got

$$Py'' + (P' + f)y' + f'y = 0 \implies P = P, Q = P' + f, R = f'$$

Comment: For an example, check out https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-equations/second-order-differential-equations/linear-homogeneous-2nd-order/v/2nd-order-linear-homogeneous-differential-equations-1

Comment: okay I didn't realize that you could just do a change of variable and substitute. Now do I just solve that last equation the way second order differential equations are normally solved?

Comment: No, take the differentials of the values I stated above, substitute them in $P'' - Q' + R = 0$ and show that it satisfies the equation.

Comment: take differentials of P, Q, and R or of the expanded equation?

Comment: I'll write a post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
[P(x)y']' + [f(x)y]' &= P'(x)y' + P(x)y'' + f'(x)y + f(x)y' \\
&= P(x)y'' + [P'(x) + f(x)]y' + f'(x)y \\
&= 0
\end{align}$$

Equating with $P_*(x)y'' + Q_*(x)y' + R_*(x)y = 0$, we find

$$\begin{align}
P_*(x) &= P(x) \\
Q_*(x) &= P'(x) + f(x) \\
R_*(x) &= f'(x)
\end{align}$$

Now, we know that the solutions to the ODE are a basis and hence are non zero. So to make our exact equation equal to zero, we need to show

$$\begin{align}
0 &= P_*''(x) - Q_*'(x) + R_*(x) \\
&= P''(x) -[P''(x) + f'(x)] + f'(x) \ \ \ \ \ \ (1) \\
&= [P''(x) - P''(x)] + [f'(x) - f'(x)] \\
&= 0
\end{align}$$

Where at $(1)$ we substituted in the differentials.

Comment: If you need anymore help, just post below here. Also, if you like my answer could accept it and upvote it please.

Comment: I accepted your answer. Thanks so much! There's a  second part where I need to use that last condition to prove a second order equation is exact. I'm currently trying to work through it but I will definitely come back with questions. You are so helpful thank you again!

Comment: It's all good mate, though I'm going to bed now so if you need help, just ask and I'll get back to you in the morning.

Comment: great thanks again!

Comment: Okay I've been working for about an hour and have no idea where to go with this second part. Also I tried putting it in the correct format but once I posted it looked like a mess. So using the previous condition P''(x)-Q'(x)+R(x)=0, show that the following equation is exact then use the exact form to find the general solution. the equation is y''+xy'+y=0. It should also be noted that apparently I will need to integrate the equation once and then apply the appropriate first order method. I am just getting very confused.

Comment: Post a new question to MSE and I'll answer it there.