# Solving exact second order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I just started reading about second order differential equations and I have issue with exact equations. In the book I'm reading from, says,

> The equation $p(x)y''+q(x)y'+r(x)y=s(x)$ is exact if we have
> $p''-q'+r=0$. These type of equations can be solve with the following
> method,
>
> $$\frac d{dx}(py'+(q-p)y)=s(x)\xrightarrow{\int} \text{ first order
>  linear differential equation} \Rightarrow \ldots$$

I tried to find elementary proofs for why exact equations can be solve as mentioned in the book but some of them was too advanced for me like [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_differential_equation) and I found a similar question on this site [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1135091/can-someone-give-me-an-example-of-how-to-work-out-an-exact-linear-second-order-d?noredirect=1)  which states that

> If an equation $P(x)y''+Q(x)y'+R(x)y=0$
>
> can be written in the form:
>
> $$[P(x)y']'+[f(x)y]'=0$$
>
> then the equation is said to be exact.

And it cause more confusion for me because in the book says RHS is a function $s(x)$ but here RHS is zero.

Can you please prove the statement in the book?

Comment: You have mistake. It should be $$\frac d{dx}(py'+(q-p')y)=s(x)$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$p(x)y''+q(x)y'+r(x)y=s(x)$$
$$p(x)y''+q(x)y'+(q'-p'')y=s(x)$$
$$p(x)y''+(q(x)y)'-p''y=s(x)$$
$$p(x)y''\color {red}{+p'y'}+(q(x)y)'\color{red}{-p'y'}-p''y=s(x)$$
$$(p(x)y')'+(q(x)y)'-(p'y)'=s(x)$$
It's easy to integrate now.

Comment: It's clear now. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome @MasterShifu